# Is it possible to navigate from feature file to step definition and vice versa in Cypress (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, cypress, shortcut

I'm using cypress cucumber test framework and IDE VSCode
I can't find a way to navigate from feature to step definition and vice versa. I have installed Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support extension in vs code but doesn't help

Is there any config which enables navigation from feature to step definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesase navigate in VSCode **File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences > Settings on Mac)** then select **Workspace**.

[image: workspace]

Open `settings.json` file from top-right corner.

[image: settings.json]

Set following settings in your `settings.json` file and save the file. Please keep your hierarchy of files.

```
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
     "cypress/integration/*/*.js"
   ],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/integration/*.feature",
"cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": false,
"cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true
```

Now open your feature file, place your curson on step line, press **CTRL** and **Right click** on line or **press F12**.

Comment: I changed the hierarchy of test files and it worked. Thanks Ara Galstyan :)

Comment: Nice, glad to know!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to cypress V10, I just updated the settings.json as below:

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "cypress/e2e/**/*.js"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "/cypress/e2e/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```